# Copy values from mulit-column listbox to a sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox with column 4 columns (Name, Marital Status, Years Married, Gender). I need to copy the contents of my listbox to sheet 1. For example, if the listbox contained: Joe, Single, 0, Male then I need to have cells A2:D2 have the values Joe, Single, 0, Male, respectively.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, verifiable, complete example in your question. In other words, show us what you have done so far? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the rows/columns in a listbox, example:

```
For r = 0 to ListBox.ListCount - 1
    For c = 0 to ListBox.ListColumns.Count - 1
        Range("A2").Offset(r, c).Value = ListBox.List(r,c)
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

just changed `ListColumns.Count - 1` to `.ColumnCount - 1`

```
For r = 0 to ListBox.ListCount - 1
        For c = 0 to ListBox.ColumnCount - 1
            Range("A2").Offset(r, c).Value = ListBox.List(r,c)
        Next
    Next
```